# About the conjugacy classes of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $K_1, \cdots , K_n$ denote the conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$. For $x \in K_s$, define $n_{ijs} = |\{(y, z) \in K_i × K_j : yz = x\}|$.
>   I want to show that $n_{ijs} = n_{jis}$.

How would I begin to show this? Surely I need to show that $yz=x=zy$? But how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$yz=x=yz(y^{-1}y)= (yzy^{-1})y$$
and notice that $yzy^{-1}\in K_j$. This allows you to define an injection
$$\{(y, z) \in K_i × K_j : yz = x\}\to\{(y, z) \in K_j × K_i : yz = x\}:(y,z)\mapsto (yzy^{-1},y).$$
This shows $n_{ijs}\leq n_{jis}$; exchanging $i,j$ gives the other inequality and thus the equality.